# MySQL IF statement across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to perform multiple update on a MySQL tables using IF statements where the condition of the IF statement is in a different table to the table I'm updating. e.g I'm updating table 1 with the check in table2.

MySQL returns an error saying it is unable to find 'table2.col1'. Both the table and column exist so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error..

```
cursor = database.cursor() 
cursor.execute("""UPDATE table1 SET col1 = IF(table2.col1= 2, 3 , table1.col1),
                                    col2 = IF(table2.col1= 2 ,%s , table1.col2),
                                    col3 = IF(table2.col1= 2 , %s , table1.col3),
                                    col4 = IF(table2.col1= 2 , %s , table1.col4)                 
WHERE id =%s""", (val2, val3, val4, id))
database.commit()
```

error:

```
  _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'table2.col1' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: possibly some quotes are missing,`'table2'.col1 = 2`

Comment: You need to JOIN your other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join the table2  .try this

```
    UPDATE table1 INNER join table2
   ON ....
   SET col1 = IF.....
```